# Does video.js have a callback if unsupported?

Tags: html5-video, video.js

I'm using video.js for my html5 video, but on older devices (such as BlackBerry OS4), neither the html5 or the Flash fallback work.

Is there any way to detect this - some sort of onError callback within videojs itself, or any other way that I can detect if the video isn't supported?

I've found this code, which works for older BB, but then also detects older IE, which would run hapily with the Flash fallback.

```
function supportsVideo() {
   return !!document.createElement('video').canPlayType;
}
```

Any help or pointers would be appreciated.